# Promisejs not accurate, $getJSON in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, promise, getjson

I am using promise.js with jQuery but I do not want to use $Deferred as many say it is not accurate or best practice according to Promises/A+.

```
var promises = [];
var myArray = //something

function readFile(){
   $.getJSON( "yyy.com/readfile?callback", function( data ) {
   console.log('Reading File');
   promises.push(data)
   });
}

function writeFile(){
   $.getJSON( "yyy.com/writefile?callback", function( data ) {
   console.log('Writing File');
   promises.push(data)
   });
}


for(var i, i < myArray.length, i ++) {
    readFile();
    writeFile();
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
console.log('ALL DONE!');
// Do something
});
```

**This is the result**

All Done!
Reading File
Writing File
Reading File
Writing File
Reading File
Writing File


Something must be wrong with my code. The "All Done" should be log at the last. Can someone guide me in this?

Comment: I dont know how promise lib works, but i think the promises should be function to be done

Comment: an interface need not be 100% PromisesA+ compat to work, so $Deferred should work ok.

Comment: You will need to fill the `promises` array with actual promises, not with `data` that arrives asynchronously!

Comment: Hi Dandavis, agree but I still think it is important to keep myself in good practice according to PromisesA+

Comment: Hi Bergi, you were right. I should filled the array with actual promises. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data returned from your `getJSON` calls is most certainly not a promise. From the promisejs site (https://www.promisejs.org/), you can just convert the jQuery promise to a Promise object using:

```
var jQueryPromise = $.ajax('/data.json');
var realPromise = Promise.resolve(jQueryPromise);
```

What this will look like in your example is something like the following:

```
var promises = [];
var myArray = //something

function readFile(){
   return Promise.resolve($.getJSON( "yyy.com/readfile?callback", function( data ) {
     console.log('Reading File');
   }));
}

function writeFile(){
   return Promise.resolve($.getJSON( "yyy.com/writefile?callback", function( data ) {
     console.log('Writing File');
   }));
}


for(var i, i < myArray.length, i ++) {
    promises.push(readFile());
    promises.push(writeFile());
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
  console.log('ALL DONE!');
  // Do something
});
```

**Comment update**:
If you are wanting your promises to be handled sequentially, you should use `.then`, for example:

```
for(var i, i < myArray.length, i ++) {
    var operationPromise = readFile().then(function(readFileResponse){
        return writeFile(readFileResponse);
    });
    promises.push(operationPromise);
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help. One last thing, as it is still async, what if I want guarantee that readFile() is resolve then writeFile() is resolve then etc. :)

Comment: I updated my answer with info on how to accomplish your goal. :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! It worked, readFile() followed by writeFile() but there is one issue. The Promise.All(promises) wouldn't work for this code. Maybe it doesn't know when operationPromise is resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you call `Promise.all(promises)`, `promises` is still empty (from the above). `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, meaning that it will go off to the side and run it.

A timeline:

1. `promises = [];`
2. readFile and writeFile are defined
3. readFile and writeFile get called a bunch, and go to the side.
4. `Promise.all(promises)` gets called, and `promises` is still empty.
5. Because the promise doesn't have anything to do, it returns immediately.
6. Around this time, the `$.getJSON`s should return and add to the `promises` variable.

Additionally, I'm pretty sure you're using promises incorrectly, but I don't know enough about them to confirm.

Comment: Yes you were right, promises is still empty. Cheers.